# Can multiple entry schengen visa have a validity longer than 90 days?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, repeat-visits

So im planning to invite a friend to visit me. I want him to visit me twice. Once for 15 days in february 2020 and then for 75 days in may/june. Is it possible that he applies for the visit visa once only and be able to get a visa from february to june with multiple entries allowed? His total duration wont exceed 90 days.

Edit:
My friend has had many schengen visas  before and never over stayed

Comment: Has your friend held a Schengen visa previously? Has he considered requesting a two-entry visa?

Comment: Yes he had many visas before. I guess two entries will suffice. My question is can they issue a visa sticker for a  longer time period than 90days which is what typically happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Schengen visas can be issued for up to five years.  The maximum duration of stay is 90 days, but if the period of validity is longer than six months then the stay is limited to 90 days in each 180-day period.

Your friend can submit a visa application for both trips at once.  If the application is successful, the visa officer ought to give a period of validity at least sufficient for both trips, and either a two-entry or multiple-entry visa.

Comment: Based on my own experience in the past, whether you apply for a single- or multiple entry visa depends entirely on your own choice (the price is higher for multiple entry, if I remember correctly). You shouldn't need to specify more than the first visit on the application - I've got Schengen visa for 5 years, specifying only a short 3-day break in France. It's my impression that they don't give out the full 5 year ones on the first application, though. Another thing, I always include some words about why I want a long visa - things like wanting to come back regularly etc.